# Setting output in one array

Tags: arrays, output

I need quick help how to put 3 line of output code in one string.
With this code i get answer:

```
 Duplicate Element : 12
 Duplicate Element : 0
 Duplicate Element : 43
```

but I want them to be in one array.

```
public class As1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []array= {12,23,-22,0,43,545,-4,-55,43,12,0,-999,-87};


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++)
            {
                if ((array[i] == array[j]) && (i != j))
                {
                    System.out.println("Duplicate Element : "+array[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can use `array.toString[]`, but I get error.
I want my output to be like this

> `Duplicate Element : 12, 0, 43.`

Comment: I honestly dont understand the question you want.  Take a step back, think about the problem.  Write a clear and concise question with your code, to include your question and We should be of more help.

Comment: it isn't array.toString[], instead it should be `Arrays.toString()`.. I don't know what you intend to do with this.. but the syntax was wrong and had to point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can always make one-time print with boolean flag like **first**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

    boolean first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if ((array[i] == array[j]) && (i != j)) {
                if(first) {
                    System.out.print("Duplicate Element:");
                    first = false;
                }
                System.out.print(" " + array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can create a new array that has all the duplicates and print them afterwards:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

    int[] duplicates = new int[array.length/2]; //maximum duplicates is half of size the given integer array
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if ((array[i] == array[j]) && (i != j)) {
                duplicates[k] = array[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Duplicate Element:");
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + duplicates[i]);
    }
}
```